# Как добавить точку для псевдоэлемнта?

Tags: css

В стилях есть псевдоэлемент **.decorated-zone::before** с текстом "REC" .  По макету нужно добавить еще точку со стилями .

Стили для точки такие:

```
fill: #FF0070;
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #FF0070);
```

Вопрос: как в псевдоэлемент добавить такую точку ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.page {
  font-family: IBM Plex Mono;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: url("https://s1.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2023/11/8e263f969c2107e4630ae3a539834a22.png");
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


/*header*/

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.decorated-zone::before {
  content: 'REC';
  color: var(--accent-color);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 33px;
}

.header__theme-menu {
  justify-self: end;
}

.header__theme-menu-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.header__theme-menu-button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: var(--accent-color);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px, 13px;
}

.header__theme-menu-button_active {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--accent-color);
}

.title {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 116px;
  line-height: 82.5%;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px var(--accent-color);
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.title_description {
  justify-self: end;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 355px;
  /* максимальная ширина блока */
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: var(--accent-color);
}


/*Адаптив для планшетов*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1023.99px) {
  .header {
    gap: 162px;
    justify-content: normal;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 120px;
  }
  .title_description {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 491px;
  }
}


/*Адаптив для десктоп*/

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .header {
    gap: 162px;
    justify-content: normal;
    align-items: start
  }
  .header__theme-menu {
    justify-self: center;
  }
  .header__theme-menu-list {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 157px;
  }
  .title_description {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Сложно сосредоточиться</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body class="page">
  <header class="header decorated-zone">
    <nav class="header__theme-menu">
      <ul class="header__theme-menu-list">
        <li class="header__theme-menu-item">
          <button class="header__theme-menu-button header__theme-menu-button_type_light">
              День
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="header__theme-menu-item">
          <button class="header__theme-menu-button header__theme-menu-button_active header__theme-menu-button_type_auto" disabled>
              Авто
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="header__theme-menu-item">
          <button class="header__theme-menu-button header__theme-menu-button_type_dark">
              Неон
            </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="title">no focus</h1>
    <p class="title_description"> Что делать, когда не можешь делать ничего<br/> Или почему нам так сложно сконцентрироваться, особенно когда очень надо</p>
  </header>


  <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: никак, только сделать отдельный псевдоэлемент, например `after` или просто другой элемент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно установить `backgound-image` с нужным рисунком `svg`, затем позиционировать его как требуется с нужным размером, например:

```css
.decorated-zone::before {
  content: 'REC';
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle fill="%23FF0070" filter="drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px %23FF0070)" cx="50" cy="50" r="42" /></svg>');
  padding-right: 22px;
  background-position: center right;
  background-size: 18px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header class="header decorated-zone">
</header>
```